# Preflight 200 yet unknown CORS error on every request from Angular front end to NodeJS Express Server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, preflight

My backend server is working fine. I have thoroughly tested with Postman, and I am getting desired responses with all requests.

My angular app however, is getting a 200 Preflight response, yet an unknown CORS error on EVERY request. As far as I can see the app is set up correctly.

As can be seen below, the issue seems to be ***there is no origin header added into the final requests*** and I have no idea why not.

Express CORS implementation

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const actualOrigin = req.headers.origin;
    if (originArray.includes(actualOrigin)) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', actualOrigin);
    } else {
        return res.status(403).send('Unauthorized Origin');
    }
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

example request from FE

```
    async login(data) {
        console.log('data is: ', data);
        let sendData = {};
        if (data.loginType === 'slot') {
            sendData = {
                username: data.username,
                password: data.password,
                type: data.loginType
            };
        } else if (data.loginType === 'user_name') {
            sendData = {
                username: data.username,
                password: data.password,
                type: data.loginType
            };
        }
```

and the inspected request

```
auth.service.ts:275 Error occurred during login: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:3000/ibescore/auth/login', ok: false, …}
```

the preflight:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/ibescore/auth/login
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
http://localhost:4200
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
2
Content-Type:
text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:
Sat, 02 Sep 2023 16:21:17 GMT
Etag:
W/"2-nOO9QiTIwXgNtWtBJezz8kv3SLc"
Keep-Alive:
timeout=5
X-Powered-By:
Express
Accept:
*/*
*/
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:
authorization,content-type,x-port
Access-Control-Request-Method:
POST
Connection:
keep-alive
Host:
localhost:3000
Origin:
http://localhost:4200
Referer:
http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

and the actual request

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/ibescore/auth/login
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
*/
Authorization:
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2ODkzNjIwMDQsImV4cCI6MTY4OTM2NTYwNCwic3ViIjoidGVzdFNsb3QwMDAifQ.b7_w109hN6yG8wJCgj93l3BoKI1kvXYzDdKGbZuS-adGAFZ74_ah272ft21JrEWn3eOD_pwF6orJgYaAONyElZ3NfetF9wKHnIXxe2scAsN9G1l8mUF2gapXWlFB2Y5_9qyn38KBHG6vOqmGS0spMBTrGyZj_g9lT9mZ6-cbCxc
Content-Type:
application/json
Referer:
http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"macOS"
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Port:
4200
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Seems that your actual request doesn't contain an Origin header, but only a Referer, thus the backend will fail to set the cors headers and return with a 403 status

Comment: @derpirscher this is exactly my issue. there is no origin header present in any reqs, apart from the preflights.. and I dont know why nor how to fix it. AFAIK, I cant add an origin and value header to FE as that defeats the object of CORS

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [cors npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#usage) instead. This will handle common issues and you can focus on building your app functionality.

Install with:

```
$ npm install cors
```

And use it on the server:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: I will try it, but I really don’t think it’s a server side issue - the angular app is not sending any necessary headers

Comment: This might be useful for you to see https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors

Comment: I followed the links to 'enable-cors.org' and it seems like there is some nginx config I need to add. I will try and get back to you

Comment: What is completely mental is I have not changed anything at all, and today the system works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77029317/18227124) and expanding on it by adding a custom corsOptions has fixed the issue.

The origin property is a function that takes in the request origin and a callback as arguments. This function checks if the request origin is included in the originArray or if the origin is not defined. If either of these conditions is true, it calls the callback with null as the first argument and true as the second argument, indicating that the request is allowed. Otherwise, it calls the callback with an error object as the first argument, indicating that the request is not allowed.

```js
const corsOptions = {
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (originArray.includes(origin) || !origin) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('unauthorized Origin'));
        }
    }
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```